Replicating rows with changes to certain columns in power query
I'm trying to create a dataflow with power query for currency conversion rates. I have an excel file that has the rates I need, the issue is that the rates for the current month aren't updated until the end of the month and sometimes they're needed before that. What I'm trying to do is to use the rates for the latest month until they actually get finalized. So I'd like to duplicate all rows for the last month in the file, update the month columns by one month and keep the rates the same. Here's a sample of the data now:

And here's what I would like it to look like:


you can try this in PQ
let
    Source = Table,
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "EoM", each Date.AddMonths([Date_EoM],1)),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "BoM", each Date.AddMonths([Date_BoM],1)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Date_EoM", "Date_BoM"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"EoM", "Date_EoM"}, {"BoM", "Date_BoM"}})&Table
in
    #"Renamed Columns"



Ok so I would use that to create a new table with the estimated data, then append that new table to the existing table?

And then how could I modify that code so it only pulled the latest months data? In my sample it only shows the one previous month, but in reality the existing data goes back years.

you can modify the code to update the original table to get the output. If you want to get the latest month, you can try remove  ' &table' in the coding
